# /errors/ folder accessible?

Tags: permissions, .htaccess

I have noted that in default Magento .htaccess the /errors/ folder is accessible and open it in a browser list the content of the folder.

How to address it ?
Add `Options -Indexes` to the main `.htaccess` is safe ?

Answer (score 2):

The `errors` folder should not be accessible. [See an example here](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/errors/). Most probably you are missing something in the `.htaccess` file. Try to get one from the fresh Magento copy.
Also make sure that you have this `.htaccess` file inside the `errors` folder.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|phtml)$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: error dir list in my local

Comment: I commented out the <FilesMatch "\.(xml|phtml)$"> and </FilesMatch> to prevent the access to errors folder and we are on Litespeed. It doesn't break anything with the error pages.